# Eliminate comma from integer list input

Tags: c, file-io

I have a file, filled with integer values separated by commas. 
Example:

```
10, 5, 213
6, 21, 1
9, 21, 2
```

I am rusty with my file IO in C, and I am just caught in an infinite loop reading in the first integer value of the input(10).
Why am I stuck in a loop? Shouldn't it read in 3 numbers(ignoring commas and whitespaces) and go to the next line?

```
int main(void)
{
//Open a file to read
FILE *_file = fopen("input.txt", "r");
//Used for scanning characters
int i[3];
i[0] = 0;
i[1] = 0;
i[2] = 0;
char buffer[1024] = { 0 } ;

//Check to make sure the file was open
if (_file == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: File Not Found\n");

} //Else, file was opened
else {
    //Scan the entire file and print the integer
    fscanf(_file, "%d[^,] %d[^,] %d[^,]", &i[0], &i[1], &i[2]);

    while (!feof(_file)) 
    {
        printf("%d\n", i[1]);       

        fscanf(_file, "%d[^,] %d[^,] %d[^,]", &i[0], &i[1], &i[2]);
    }


}
fclose(_file);

getchar();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: using a leading '_' in a variable name (such as _file) is a very bad idea, as the compiler creates lots of names that begin with one or two underscores that are derived from names within the program.  Therefore there can be overlap in the names.  suggest changing '_file' to something more useful, correct, and commonly used like 'fp'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you know that the file is in format `10, 5, 213`, you can use fscan() by including the commas:

```
fscanf(_file, " %d, %d, %d", &i[0], &i[1], &i[2]);
```

This will read your numbers from the file.

And make sure you check the return value from fscanf calls.

Comment: So simple, no wonder I couldn't find anything that wasn't using regex!